# Unable to stitch images

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching

I'm unable to stitch images, this is my code:

```
import cv2

stitcher = cv2.Stitcher_create(mode = 0)
foo = cv2.imread("./foo.png")
bar = cv2.imread("./bar.png")
result = stitcher.stitch(foo,bar)

cv2.imwrite("./result.jpg", result[1])
```

Both images:

- [foo.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGorS.png)
- [bar.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTpyu.png)

The result i get: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zuAY.jpg)

Comment: if you need to stitch those, and the stitcher won't cooperate, you could manually perform (write code that calls) feature extraction, matching, and estimation of a (constrained) affine transformation

Answer (score 0):

`stitcher.stitch` takes in a list of images that are to be stitched together. Change the code to:

```
result = stitcher.stitch([foo,bar])
```

Also, OpenCV is not able to stitch your two images as it is not able to find a sufficient number of keypoints. Try using other images.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I find i kind off weird that the alghoritm couldn't find a sufficient number of keypoints. Because those images clearly overlap a great deal. Will look into other images.

Comment: error code 1 stands for `cv.Stitcher_ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS`, so not necessarily number of keypoints (maybe that too but there's no evidence for that), but number of _images_ is the issue